# nested array datatables v-for vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nested

Why I can't show data from nested array with datatables in vue ?

[image]

[image]

I have a data response from API like this
[image]

and here is how my datatables look like (I'm just show tbody because in tbody shows how I get the data from API)

```
     <tbody>
        <tr
          v-for="(item, i) in items"
          :key="i"
          class="text-gray-700 border-b border-gray-200 last:border-b-0"
        >
          <td class="p-3 text-sm align-middle">
            {{ item.id }}
          </td>
          <td v-for="(field, col) in fields" :key="col" class="p-3 text-sm align-middle">
            <span>
              <span v-if="field.clickable">
                <a
                  href="#load-children"
                  @click.prevent="itemClicked(item)"
                >
                  {{ item[field.key] }}
                </a>
              </span>
              <span v-else>
                {{ item[field.key] }}
              </span>
            </span>
          </td>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

and here is the script of my datatable

```
<script>
import _ from "lodash";

export default {
  props: {
    items: { type: Array, required: true },
    fields: { type: Array, required: true },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have an array and you want to access value from the "category.name".

In JS you can not access a property of your child object with this syntax.

```js
const obj = {category: { name: 'some name'}};
console.log(obj['category.name']) // will not work it is looking for key 'category.name'
```

Because this literally expects you to have key `category.name` in obj.
It is looking for something like this

```
const obj = {"category.name": 'some name'};
```

First solutions that you could do [lodash get](https://lodash.com/docs/#get) to retrieve category.name.

Or you can refactor your code to something like `{{ item[field.key].name }}` and fields to have the only category

### Update:

I update the example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-shaw-7g88s?file=/src/App.vue) with method `showConent` where inside you can add condition depending on what parameter you have to return you that value

Comment: yes, I want to refactor my code like ```{{ item[field.key].name }}``` but I don't know how to do it

Comment: First in "datatable.fields" change "category.name" to "category". Second I think you can do something like {{ item[field.key].name || item[field.key] }}.

Comment: if I change "category.name" to "category", the content of the category column becomes like this  ```{ "id": 1, "name": "gbgb", "slug": "gbgb", "order": 0, "created_at": "01-07-2021 05:48:39" , "updated_at": "01-07-2021 05:48:39" }```

Comment: Yes, that is good, now you have category data. Now in a body of a table, you need `{{ item[field.key].name || item[field.key] }}`.
Where `item[field.key].name` will cover category use case and `item[field.key]` will cover other usecases.

Comment: when i use ```{{ item[field.key].name || item[field.key] }}```  the response data is empty (not only in category, but also in title, and status

Comment: I created an example in codesandbox. Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-shaw-7g88s?file=/src/App.vue)
Let me know if I missed the structure you have

Comment: okey, thx you bro, it works. yesterday I put ```item[field.key]``` first not ```item[field.key].name```. But maybe you have another like putting a variable to show data inside child obj dinamically? maybe like ```item[field.key].child```, so I can access ```category.name``` or ```category.id``` or anything else on key

Comment: Not sure I 100% understood what you asked but maybe this helps. I update the example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-shaw-7g88s?file=/src/App.vue:1472-1509) with method `showConent` where inside you can add condition depending on what parameter you have to return you that value. Did this answer your question?

Comment: thx you bro, maybe you can edit your answer with that comment